# replace word in string

Tags: c, string, strcmp, strstr

this is an example of what I wanna do
I have the following list

```
[token]
[token1]
[token22]
[token99]
[8token]
[3token3]
```

and I wanna remove "[" and "]" then replace the word token with my own word. so I have the following code:

```
char *getToken(char *repl, char *mysrc)
{
    const char *p1 = strstr(mysrc,"[")+1;
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1,"]");
    size_t len = p2-p1;
    char *src = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strncpy(src,p1,len);
    src[len] = '\0';

    char *find = "token";
    char *found;
    if(strcmp(src,find) == 0)
        return src;
    char *res = malloc(strlen(src) + strlen(repl) + 1);
    if (res == NULL)
        return src;
    found = strstr(src, find);
    /* Search string not found, return the whole of the source */
    if (found == NULL){
        strcpy(res, src);
        return res;
    }
    /* Paste the replacement string in */
    strncpy(res, src, (size_t)(found - src));
    strcat(res, repl);
    strcat(res, found + strlen(find));
    free(src);
    return res;
}
```

which is working fine except that in some situations I get an X or H in front of the result. like this: Xtest22 instead of test22

*Did I do something wrong with strlen?* I can't seem to find out where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: FYI, that last early return is leaking memory (`src`). Also, `strnlen` is much safer than `strlen`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: You don't have to cast the return value of malloc and you don't have to use sizeof(char)

Comment: could leaking memory be a reason ? how can I avoid leaking memory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could happen when the `"token"` string ends up at the beginning of the string after the removal of the square brackets: in this case, `(size_t)(found - src)` evaluates to zero, so the call of

```
strncpy(res, src, (size_t)(found - src));
```

does not change the `res` string at all, leaving whatever junk that was there for the following call of `strcat` to skip before appending. You get lucky that the junk in the `res` happens to be a short null-terminated string, such as an `"X"` or an `"H"`. Otherwise, you could get a much longer string of arbitrary characters.

In addition to fixing the above undefined behavior, you should fix a few more things:

- Your code does not check the return value of the first `malloc`.
- Your code miscalculates the length of the result: you should subtractl the length of the word `"token"`, because you replace it with the content of `repl`, i.e. it should be `malloc(strlen(src) + strlen(repl) - strlen(find) + 1)`
- You do not need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C
- You do not need to multiply the length by `sizeof(char)` (only one of your two `malloc`s does that)
- Your second early return leaks memory.

Comment: I assume that you understand how to fix the undefined behavior: all you need is to set `res[0]` to `'\0'` before calling `strncpy`.

Comment: it is working perfectly now. thank you! can you give me a hint please about how to avoid memory leak on second return ?

Comment: @SamReina One way to avoid the memory leak would be to `free(res)` and `return src` inside the `if (found == NULL)` conditional.